# Create Log File in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below code and currently it loads all the information on screen. I want it to log to a log file on D:\Apps\Logs.

The log file needs to have the name of the computer it is loading against - so COMPUTERNAME.log

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

```
$computer = gc env:computername

$onetcp = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart).tostring() $twotcp = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart).tostring() $threetcp = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart).tostring() $fourtcp = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart).tostring()


$onedfsr = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart).tostring() $twodfsr = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart).tostring() $threedfsr = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart).tostring() $fourdfsr = ((get-childitem c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart).tostring()

write-host TCPIP.sys Version on $computer is: "$onetcp.$twotcp.$threetcp.$fourtcp" Write-Host write-host DFSRS.exe Version on $computer is: "$onedfsr.$twodfsr.$threedfsr.$fourdfsr"

Write-Host

If (get-wmiobject win32_share | where-object {$_.Name -eq "REMINST"}) {   Write-Host "The REMINST share exists on $computer" } Else {   Write-Host "The REMINST share DOES NOT exist on $computer - Please create as per standards"  }   Write-Host

$hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB2450944 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $hotfix2 = Get-HotFix -Id KB2582284 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $hotfix3 = Get-HotFix -Id KB979808 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If ($hotfix1) {     Write-Host "Hotfix KB2450944 is installed"
-BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black   } else {    Write-Host "Hotfix KB2450944 is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix" -ForegroundColor "red"   }


If ($hotfix2) {     Write-Host "Hotfix KB2582284 is installed"
-BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black   } else {    Write-Host "Hotfix KB2582284 is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix" -ForegroundColor "red"   }

If ($hotfix3) {     Write-Host "Hotfix KB979808 is installed"
-BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black   } else {    Write-Host "Hotfix KB979808 is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix" -ForegroundColor "red"    }
```

Comment: Log : The term 'Log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Do you have a log Function too?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Put this at the top of your file:

```
$Logfile = "D:\Apps\Logs\$(gc env:computername).log"

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}
```

Then replace your `Write-host` calls with `LogWrite`.

Comment: thanks for that - works fine but it does not display the TCPIP.sys version now - it just shows "TCPIP.sys" - the same for DFSR.exe. I changed the Write-Host to LogWrite but those two are not showing the version in the log file.

Also, any idea how I am re-write the log file each time it is run? Currently it appends the log file; would like it if it can just create a new each time. Thanks.

Comment: For properties of an object, you need to encapsulate the whole thing in parentheses with a $ at he front.  Try changing it to: `$(TCPIP.sys)`

Comment: To get the log file to remake each time, you need to add another section at the top to delete/create the file if it exists.

Comment: Just a side note, you can embed the computer name in a string, using the $env variable, without using `get-content` and a variable assignment. `Write-Host "My local computer name is: $env:computername"`

Comment: I also like to use the -passthrough flag so that the logging also outputs to the shell window.

Comment: I would suggest to name your function according to the naming convention for known verbs: Write-Log

Answer (score 85):

A function that takes these principles a little further.

1. Add's timestamps - can't have a log without timestamps.
2. Add's a level (uses INFO by default) meaning you can highlight big issues.
3. Allows for optional console output. If you don't set a log destination, it simply pumps it out.

   ```
   Function Write-Log {
       [CmdletBinding()]
       Param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
       [ValidateSet("INFO","WARN","ERROR","FATAL","DEBUG")]
       [String]
       $Level = "INFO",

       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [string]
       $Message,

       [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
       [string]
       $logfile
       )

       $Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
       $Line = "$Stamp $Level $Message"
       If($logfile) {
           Add-Content $logfile -Value $Line
       }
       Else {
           Write-Output $Line
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: How does this output to a file? When I tested it, it only output to console.

Comment: @Aaron you need to specify a target output file with the `$logfile` parameter on each use of the function. I included at the beginning of my script a check for if the file did not exist and if not created it. This function successfully output to my file as expected.

Answer (score 58):

I believe this is the simplest way of putting all what it is on the screen into a file. It is a native PS CmdLet so you don't have to change or install anything in your script

```
Start-Transcript -Path Computer.log

Write-Host "everything will end up in Computer.log"

Stop-Transcript
```

You can also add `-Append` to append instead the content [Thanks @scipilot for the tip!]

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Its native and minimal.

Comment: Very simple to use. I would suggest adding `-Append` or `NoClobber` otherwise it overwrites the log. Also note it outputs a lot of stuff about the process and host machine as a header, so it's not directly equivalent to what is on screen, unless you play with the `-UseMinimalHeader` etc params.

Answer (score 10):

```
function WriteLog
{
    Param ([string]$LogString)
    $LogFile = "C:\$(gc env:computername).log"
    $DateTime = "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
    $LogMessage = "$Datetime $LogString"
    Add-content $LogFile -value $LogMessage
}

WriteLog "This is my log message"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using this [`Log-Entry` framework:](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry)

**Script:**

```
Function Main {
    Log -File "D:\Apps\Logs\$Env:computername.log"

    $tcp = (get-childitem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductVersionRaw
    $dfs = (get-childitem C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\dfsvc.exe).Versioninfo.ProductVersionRaw

    Log "TCPIP.sys Version on $computer is:" $tcp
    Log "DFSVC.exe Version on $computer is:" $dfs

    If (get-wmiobject win32_share | where-object {$_.Name -eq "REMINST"}) {Log "The REMINST share exists on $computer"}
    Else {Log "The REMINST share DOES NOT exist on $computer - Please create as per standards"}

    "KB2450944", "KB3150513", "KB3176935" | ForEach {
        $hotfix = Get-HotFix -Id $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($hotfix) {Log -Color Green Hotfix $_ is installed}
        Else {Log -Color Red Hotfix $_ " is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix"}
    }
}
```

**Screen output:**
[image: Screen output]

**Log File** (at `D:\Apps\Logs\<computername>.log`):

```
2017-05-31  Write-Log (version: 01.00.02, PowerShell version: 5.1.14393.1198)
19:19:29.00 C:\Users\User\PowerShell\Write-Log\Check.ps1 
19:19:29.47 TCPIP.sys Version on  is: {Major: 10, Minor: 0, Build: 14393, Revision: 1066, MajorRevision: 0, MinorRevision: 1066}
19:19:29.50 DFSVC.exe Version on  is: {Major: 2, Minor: 0, Build: 50727, Revision: 8745, MajorRevision: 0, MinorRevision: 8745}
19:19:29.60 The REMINST share DOES NOT exist on  - Please create as per standards
Error at 25,13: Cannot find the requested hotfix on the 'localhost' computer. Verify the input and run the command again.
19:19:33.41 Hotfix KB2450944 is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix
19:19:37.03 Hotfix KB3150513 is installed
19:19:40.77 Hotfix KB3176935 is installed
19:19:40.77 End
```

Answer (score 4):

Gist with log rotation: https://gist.github.com/barsv/85c93b599a763206f47aec150fb41ca0

Usage:

```
. .\logger.ps1
Write-Log "debug message"
Write-Log "info message" "INFO"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with this code for a while now and I have something that works well for me. Log files are numbered with leading '0' but retain their file extension. And I know everyone likes to make functions for everything but I started to remove functions that performed 1 simple task. Why use many word when few do trick? Will likely remove other functions and perhaps create functions out of other blocks. I keep the logger script in a central share and make a local copy if it has changed, or load it from the central location if needed.

First I import the logger:

```
#Change directory to the script root
cd $PSScriptRoot

#Make a local copy if changed then Import logger
if(test-path "D:\Scripts\logger.ps1"){
    if (Test-Path "\\<server>\share\DCS\Scripts\logger.ps1") {
        if((Get-FileHash "\\<server>\share\DCS\Scripts\logger.ps1").Hash -ne (Get-FileHash "D:\Scripts\logger.ps1").Hash){
            rename-Item -path "..\logger.ps1" -newname "logger$(Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd-HH.mm.ss').ps1" -force
            Copy-Item "\\<server>\share\DCS\Scripts\logger.ps1" -destination "..\" -Force 
        }
    }
}else{
    Copy-Item "\\<server>\share\DCS\Scripts\logger.ps1" -destination "..\" -Force
}
. "..\logger.ps1"
```

Define the log file:

```
$logfile = (get-location).path + "\Log\" + $QProfile.replace(" ","_") + "-$metricEnv-$ScriptName.log"
```

What I log depends on debug levels that I created:

```
if ($Debug -ge 1){
    $message = "<$pid>Debug:$Debug`-Adding tag `"MetricClass:temp`" to $host_name`:$metric_name"
    Write-Log $message $logfile "DEBUG"
}
```

I would probably consider myself a bit of a "hack" when it comes to coding so this might not be the prettiest but here is my version of `logger.ps1`:

```
# all logging settins are here on top
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$logFile = "$(gc env:computername).log",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$logLevel = "DEBUG", # ("DEBUG","INFO","WARN","ERROR","FATAL")
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int64]$logSize = 10mb,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$logCount = 25
) 
# end of settings

function Write-Log-Line ($line, $logFile) {
    $logFile | %{ 
           If (Test-Path -Path $_) { Get-Item $_ } 
           Else { New-Item -Path $_ -Force } 
    } | Add-Content -Value $Line -erroraction SilentlyCOntinue
}

function Roll-logFile
{
    #function checks to see if file in question is larger than the paramater specified if it is it will roll a log and delete the oldes log if there are more than x logs.
    param(
        [string]$fileName = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")+".log", 
        [int64]$maxSize = $logSize, 
        [int]$maxCount = $logCount
    )
    $logRollStatus = $true
    if(test-path $filename) {
        $file = Get-ChildItem $filename
        # Start the log-roll if the file is big enough

        #Write-Log-Line "$Stamp INFO Log file size is $($file.length), max size $maxSize" $logFile
        #Write-Host "$Stamp INFO Log file size is $('{0:N0}' -f $file.length), max size $('{0:N0}' -f $maxSize)"
        if($file.length -ge $maxSize) {
            Write-Log-Line "$Stamp INFO Log file size $('{0:N0}' -f $file.length) is larger than max size $('{0:N0}' -f $maxSize). Rolling log file!" $logFile
            #Write-Host "$Stamp INFO Log file size $('{0:N0}' -f $file.length) is larger than max size $('{0:N0}' -f $maxSize). Rolling log file!"
            $fileDir = $file.Directory
            $fbase = $file.BaseName
            $fext = $file.Extension
            $fn = $file.name #this gets the name of the file we started with

            function refresh-log-files {
                 Get-ChildItem $filedir | ?{ $_.Extension -match "$fext" -and $_.name -like "$fbase*"} | Sort-Object lastwritetime
            }
            function fileByIndex($index) {
                $fileByIndex = $files | ?{($_.Name).split("-")[-1].trim("$fext") -eq $($index | % tostring 00)}
                #Write-Log-Line "LOGGER: fileByIndex = $fileByIndex" $logFile
                $fileByIndex
            }
            function getNumberOfFile($theFile) {
                $NumberOfFile = $theFile.Name.split("-")[-1].trim("$fext")
                if ($NumberOfFile -match '[a-z]'){
                    $NumberOfFile = "01"
                }
                #Write-Log-Line "LOGGER: GetNumberOfFile = $NumberOfFile" $logFile
                $NumberOfFile
            }

            refresh-log-files | %{
                [int32]$num = getNumberOfFile $_
                Write-Log-Line "LOGGER: checking log file number $num" $logFile
                if ([int32]$($num | % tostring 00) -ge $maxCount) {
                    write-host "Deleting files above log max count $maxCount : $_"
                    Write-Log-Line "LOGGER: Deleting files above log max count $maxCount : $_" $logFile
                    Remove-Item $_.fullName
                }
            }

            $files = @(refresh-log-files)

            # Now there should be at most $maxCount files, and the highest number is one less than count, unless there are badly named files, eg non-numbers
            for ($i = $files.count; $i -gt 0; $i--) {
                $newfilename = "$fbase-$($i | % tostring 00)$fext"
                #$newfilename = getFileNameByNumber ($i | % tostring 00) 
                if($i -gt 1) {
                    $fileToMove = fileByIndex($i-1)
                } else {
                    $fileToMove = $file
                }
                if (Test-Path $fileToMove.PSPath) { # If there are holes in sequence, file by index might not exist. The 'hole' will shift to next number, as files below hole are moved to fill it
                    write-host "moving '$fileToMove' => '$newfilename'"
                    #Write-Log-Line "LOGGER: moving $fileToMove => $newfilename" $logFile
                    # $fileToMove is a System.IO.FileInfo, but $newfilename is a string. Move-Item takes a string, so we need full path
                    Move-Item ($fileToMove.FullName) -Destination $fileDir\$newfilename -Force
                }
            }
        } else {
            $logRollStatus = $false
        }
    } else {
        $logrollStatus = $false
    }
    $LogRollStatus
}


Function Write-Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]
    $Message,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [String]
    $logFile = "log-$(gc env:computername).log",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [String]
    $Level = "INFO"
    )
    #Write-Host $logFile
    $levels = ("DEBUG","INFO","WARN","ERROR","FATAL")
    $logLevelPos = [array]::IndexOf($levels, $logLevel)
    $levelPos = [array]::IndexOf($levels, $Level)
    $Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff")

    # First roll the log if needed to null to avoid output
    $Null = @(
        Roll-logFile -fileName $logFile -filesize $logSize -logcount $logCount
    )

    if ($logLevelPos -lt 0){
        Write-Log-Line "$Stamp ERROR Wrong logLevel configuration [$logLevel]" $logFile
    }

    if ($levelPos -lt 0){
        Write-Log-Line "$Stamp ERROR Wrong log level parameter [$Level]" $logFile
    }

    # if level parameter is wrong or configuration is wrong I still want to see the 
    # message in log
    if ($levelPos -lt $logLevelPos -and $levelPos -ge 0 -and $logLevelPos -ge 0){
        return
    }

    $Line = "$Stamp $Level $Message"
    Write-Log-Line $Line $logFile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to use the new TUN.Logging PowerShell module, this can also send a log mail. Just use the Start-Log and/or Start-MailLog cmdlets to start logging and then just use Write-HostLog, Write-WarningLog, Write-VerboseLog, Write-ErrorLog etc. to write to console and log file/mail. Then call Send-Log and/or Stop-Log at the end and voila, you got your logging.
Just install it from the PowerShell Gallery via

```bsh
Install-Module -Name TUN.Logging
```

Or just follow the link: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/TUN.Logging

Documentation of the module can be found here: https://github.com/echalone/TUN/blob/master/PowerShell/Modules/TUN.Logging/TUN.Logging.md