# logfile output not capturing all data

Tags: powershell

For Powershell v2

I have the below code (it is only a subsection of a mass code I have been working on). The whole thing had write-host all over the place and I have been asked to see if I can put it to a log file. Using this link I have followed the steps and tried loads of other things but I just cannot get the all the output working:

[Create Log File in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834656/create-log-file-in-powershell)

A lot of the things are just not appearing on the logfile - it is just blank in the logfile but shows the ouput on the screen- ie:

1. Any of the WMI call output - ie

   > @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption,
   >   BuildNumber, CountryCode, CSDVersion, CSName, InstallDate,
   >   @{Name=”Physical Memory Free”;Expression={“{0:N1}GB”
   >   -f($*.FreePhysicalMemory/1mb)}}, @{Name=”Free Space In Paging Files”;Expression={“{0:N1}GB” -f($*.FreeSpaceInPagingFiles/1mb)}},
   >   @{Name=”Free Virtual Memory”;Expression={“{0:N1}GB”
   >   -f($_.FreeVirtualMemory/1mb)}} | Format-List)
2. Any of the commands that are just run: ie `net localgroup administrators`

There are a lot more as well but it seems like it is mostly all WMI calls.

Here is the part of codes that have issues:

NETWORK PART:

```
$forward = nslookup $computername


$reverse = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($computername) | select -Expa AddressList | select -Expa ipaddresstostring | % { nslookup $_ }

LogWrite "Doing forward lookup: "
$forward
LogWrite `r`n
LogWrite "Doing reverse lookup: "
$reverse

#$computername = gc env:computername
#$serverName = SV180515

$NicConfig = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computername
$myCol = @()
ForEach ($Nic in $NicConfig)
{
    If ($Nic.IPAddress -ne $null)
    {
        $myObj = "" | Select-Object Description, DHCPEnabled, IPAddress, IPSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, DNSServers, WINSServers, NICModel, SpeedDuplex
        $myObj.Description = $Nic.Description
        $myObj.DHCPEnabled = $Nic.DHCPEnabled
        $myObj.IPAddress = $Nic.IPAddress
        $myObj.IPSubnet = $Nic.IPSubnet
        $myObj.DefaultIPGateway = $Nic.DefaultIPGateway
        $myObj.DNSServers = $Nic.DNSServerSearchOrder
        $myObj.WINSServers = $Nic.WINSPrimaryServer,$Nic.WINSSecondaryServer
        $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $computername)
        $baseKey = $registry.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}")
        $subKeyNames = $baseKey.GetSubKeyNames()
        ForEach ($subKeyName in $subKeyNames)
        {
            $subKey = $baseKey.OpenSubKey("$subKeyName")
            $ID = $subKey.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId")
            If ($ID -eq $Nic.SettingId)
            {
                $componentID = $subKey.GetValue("ComponentID")
                If ($componentID -match "ven_14e4")
                {
                    $myObj.NICModel = "Broadcom"
                    $requestedMediaType = $subKey.GetValue("RequestedMediaType")
                    $enum = $subKey.OpenSubKey("Ndi\Params\RequestedMediaType\Enum")
                    $myObj.SpeedDuplex = $enum.GetValue("$requestedMediaType")
                }
                ElseIf ($componentID -match "ven_8086")
                {
                    $myObj.NICModel = "Intel"
                    $SD = $subKey.GetValue("*SpeedDuplex")
                    $enum = $subKey.OpenSubKey("Ndi\Params\*SpeedDuplex\Enum")
                    $myObj.SpeedDuplex = $enum.GetValue("$SD")
                }
                ElseIf ($componentID -match "b06bdrv")
                {
                    $myObj.NICModel = "Broadcom"
                    $SD = $subKey.GetValue("*SpeedDuplex")
                    $enum = $subKey.OpenSubKey("BRCMndi\Params\*SpeedDuplex\Enum")
                    $myObj.SpeedDuplex = $enum.GetValue("$SD")
                }
                Else
                {
                    $myObj.NICModel = "unknown"
                    $myObj.SpeedDuplex = "unknown"
                }
            }
        }
        $myCol += $myObj
    }
}
$myCol
```

WMI bits:

```
#Check for local groups on server
net localgroup administrators

#checking event log for errors
LogWrite "Checking System Event log for errors"
Get-Eventlog system -newest 2000 | where {$_.entryType -match "Error"} | Format-Table TimeWritten, EventID, Message -auto

LogWrite `


LogWrite "Checking Application Event log for errors"
Get-Eventlog application -newest 2000 | where {$_.entryType -match "Error"} | Format-Table TimeWritten, EventID, Message -auto

Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select SystemName,DriveType,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name=”size(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name=”freespace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},@{Name=”Percentage(%) Free”;Expression={“{0:0}%” -f($_.freespace*100/$_.size)}}| Format-Table -AutoSize

$pagefilesize = Get-WmiObject win32_pagefile | ForEach-Object {$_.FileSize/1gb}

#LogWrite "Page File is set to"$pagefilesize"GB"

#check pagefile is systemed managed - if it is set to 0 then it is system managed
$PageFileSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFileSetting

if ($PageFileSystem.MaximumSize -eq "0")
{
LogWrite "Page File is System Managed and set to"$pagefilesize"GB"
}
else
{
LogWrite "*********ERROR - Page File is not System Mangaged*********"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

run powershell.exe -file script.ps1 *> c:\log.txt this shoud write all the output and errors in the logfile

Alternatively you can use start-transcript :

```
start-transcript -path c:\temp\mylog.txt
.\myscript.ps1
stop-transcript
```

Comment: `*>` only works on PowerShell v3 and it will still not capture write-host / Console.WriteLine output.  But if you're on V3, it is pretty much the best solution that I know of.

Comment: that partially worked...I now get all the info but the formatting is really bad. It puts every output next to each other and not on a new line...ie "This script is being run on Server2047Computer Description: TESING_SERVER, JAK R05Server Property:" - this should be split per line - one line for Computer desc and another for the name etc. Currently this puts it all into one line next to each other.

Comment: sorry - forgot to mention - this script is for Powershell v2 ..I will update the description

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered collecting your script in functions? Then you could run the functions in the script with `Out-File -Append` to log it. Replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` since write-host is interactive cmdlet. Then supply logpath in your runcommand. Here is a sample:

Untitled2.ps1

```
param($logpath)

function test {
$service = Get-Service | where {$_.status -eq "Running" } 
$service | ft name, status -auto
Write-output "hey"
ping 10.0.0.1

net localgroup
}

if($logpath) {
    #Run functions in script
    test | Out-File -Append $logpath
} else {
    #Run functions in script
    test
}
```

Then I run it with the following in cmd/bat:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -file Untitled2.ps1 -logpath "c:\users\graimer\desktop\testlog.txt"
```

Or in powershell:

```
.\Untitled2.ps1 -logpath "c:\users\graimer\desktop\testlog.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

another answer might be to capture the buffer contents after execution of the script. Look here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/10/capture-console-screen.aspx