# Should I use Write-Host or Write-Output when passing the Powershell script through user data in Terraform?

Tags: powershell, terraform

I am passing a powershell script through userdata to terraform ec2 windows instance, should I use Write-Host or Write-Output, so that the output from the script gets written to the execution log file.

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $outputFile)) {
  Write-Warning "$outputFile does not exist`r`n"
}
else {
  Write-Host "$outputFile exists`r`n"
}
```

Comment: `so that the output from the script gets written to the execution log file.` is a loaded question.
Are you looking for something similar to: `https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ScriptLogger/1.1.1/Content/Functions%5CWrite-Log.ps1`?  If you want a less complicated version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834656/create-log-file-in-powershell